# iOS Push notifications for Production

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am an Objective-C developer, and I created an app for iOS with push notifications. The only doubt 
I have to clear is that with my iPad, I am testing the push notifications with development certificates. Push notifications are working fine with developer certificates and don't work for production.

For extending it to production, will replacing the Development certificates with Production certificates be enough, or are there any other changes required?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to replacing the push certificate used by the server, you have to build the app with production or AdHoc provisioning profile, and your server should send notifications to the APNS production server.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to change the gateway to gateway.push.apple.com from sandbox in your backend code for sending notification. Also make sure that you have right certificates as suggested by others.

Comment: Can you just tell which answer solved your problem and what actually was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get it right
Developer Cert / provision + .p12 exported for developer certificate + sandbox.push.apple.com -> success
Prod Cert / provision + .p12 exported for prod cert + push.apple.com -> success

If you change the combination it will not work. Also check if Push Token (Postal) is generated by application signed with right certificate.